# Some questions about the Brillouin-Wigner form of perturbation theory

Tags: quantum-mechanics, computational-physics, perturbation-theory

I'm attempting to gain an understanding of the Brillouin-Wigner formulation of perturbation theory in quantum mechanics (I intend to write a brief summary of it for a class project encouraging us to learn and synthesise something new), and I'm stumped by a few things. I've done the Rayleigh-Schrodinger formulation of time-independent perturbation theory roughly to the level of Griffiths. I'm working from the following document:

http://www-f1.ijs.si/~ramsak/teaching/bw.pdf

1. Just before Equation (2) - the author assumes 'the usual convention' that $ <n|\psi_n>=1 $ - that is, that the perturbed and unperturbed states have an overlap of 1. I don't see why this should be true and I don't remember it popping up when I learned perturbation theory - what am I missing?
2. I notice that the degenerate case doesn't need to be treated separately here, which appeals to me. But since the energy appears on both sides, the equation for the perturbed energy has to be solved iteratively. Iterative methods like Newton-Raphson tend to converge to the solution nearest the initial guess, so what strategy can I use for numerically solving the equation that will ensure I find *all* the perturbed energies resulting from the splitting of a degenerate energy in the unperturbed case?
3. Is there a simple example of a simple problem for which the Brillouin-Wigner formulation is clearly much better than the Rayleigh-Schrodinger formulation? For example, I'd like to demonstrate a solution to perturbation theory problem that pops up in some practical application where one needs to compute higher-order corrections that would be hard to write down in the Rayleigh-Schrodinger formulation. Where would I find an example of a 'strong' perturbation that requires high-order corrections to fully appreciate the shift of the eigenenergies?

If you are aware of anything interesting I might not be aware of that's relevant to the Brillouin-Wigner formulation of perturbation theory that might be fun for me to explore, please also let me know (I've heard it's possible to organise the terms with diagrams similar to how perturbation theory is done in QFT?) - I am stumbling alone through uncharted territory here and it is always helpful to get a nudge in the right direction from someone more experienced.

Comment: Links may eventually die so would you please make your question self-contained and include the highlights of the document as part of your question?  This would also be a chance for you to contrast the treatment of these notes with other textbooks on the topic you will have read.

Comment: At least for 1. you *should* remember this condition popping up! Remember, the normalization condition to first order so that both $\langle n|n\rangle =1 =\langle\psi_n| \psi_n\rangle$ so to first  order you *need* to have the w.f. increment orthogonal to zeroth order. Maybe you didn't appreciate it then.